# Plugins for logo in wp themes?

Tags: plugins

Is there a plugin where you can upload image "logo" for use in the site's theme rather than the admin area?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. It is unclear exactly what you are looking for. Please give examples, and if appropriate, screen shots.

Comment: I don't understand as well, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. This wouldn't be a plugin since every theme is different. Some themes have this functionality built in, though.

Comment: I can only underline what john writes, some themes provide such a feature and then you can edit the header image in your backend -> appearance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no plugin that I know of, but you could add this code to your functions.php file. It would accomplish what you're looking for:

```
// Add a custom logo to the admin pages.  Image _MUST_ be 30x31, located in the theme images folder and named 'admin-logo.gif'.
function admin_logo() {
    $logo = dirname(__FILE__).'/images/admin-logo.gif';
    $logourl = get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/admin-logo.gif';

    if (file_exists($logo)) {
        echo '
            <style type="text/css">
                #header-logo { background-image: url('.$logourl.') !important; }
            </style>
        ';
    }
}

add_action('admin_head', 'admin_logo');
```

The function will check the images folder in your theme for a file named admin-logo.gif, and if found will add a CSS call to the page header to replace the stock WP logo. As mentioned in the comment, the image **MUST** be 30x31 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

The logo is controlled by the theme ... so you'll have to use a theme that offers that option.

Alternatively, you could edit the them to change the logo.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on using a theme that supports logos.  Unless you are an experienced developer you really want to do as little editing of CSS and PHP as possible.